# Diffraction of already diffracted light

Tags: diffraction

What will happen if diffracted light encounters another aperture in its path and gets diffracted once again? What will be the final result? How it will be different from the one-time diffraction pattern? Does anybody know any references?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can diffract many times. For example, in Young's double slit experiment, he is using a single slit first to make the light coherent(path lengths to each double slit are the same from the point source), then the double slit to make his fringes. 
[image]

Comment: What I have in my problem is two circular apertures at different distances from the source. Light first encounters one aperture and after the second aperture. Do you know any reference that deals with such a problem?

Comment: @Ash Young's double slit. See edit.